# Do this script is right to give expected output?

Tags: unix, awk, aggregate

Will this script give expected output .Provided files are sample files(small 
in size). Need to find the columns name from input file and according to 
columns names do aggregations on it to get generate report. If not then what 
will the possible solution.

```
   #!/bin/sh
    temp_file1=$(mktemp /tmp/temp_file1.XXXXX)
    contact=""
    not_Type=""
    count=""
    awk 'BEGIN{
        OFS=FS=","
           split(target,fields,FS)
              for (i in fields)
                  print i
                     field_idx[fields[i]] = i
                     print field_idx[fields[i]]
                       }
                      NR==1 {
                         for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)
                              head[i] = $i
                              print $head[i]
                              next
                            } ' $1 > temp_file1
    myarr=( $( cat temp_file1 ) )  # to get the columns name in temp file

    for i in ${myarr[*]}    #To check required columns to do aggregations
    do
            case i in
              Contact_Id)
                contact=Contact_id ;;
              Not_Type)
                not_Type=Not_Type ;;
              Count)
                count=Count ;;
              esac
    done
```

## actual aggregations logic

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{a[$contact OFS $not_Type)]+=1}END{for(i in a)print i,a[i]}'  $1 > $2
```

Note:-It is giving error at line no 1. for awk command

> `awk: 0602-562 Field $() is not correct.`
>   `The input line number is 1.`
>   `The source line number is 12.`
>   `a.sh[20]: 0403-057 Syntax error at line 20 : '(' is not expected.`

input :-

```
Sr_No,Contact_Id,Not_Type,Count

1,A,RC,1
2,B,OTC,1
3,C,RC,1
4,A,OTC,1
5,D,PB,1
6,A,RC,1
7,B,OTC,1
```

Expected OutPut:-

```
Sr_No,Contact_Id,Not_Type,Count

A,OTC,1
A,RC,2
B,OTC,2
C,RC,1
D,PB,1
```

Thanks in advance.